# JPA multithreaded inserts

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, jpa, locking

I am using MS SQL Server, and my program recently started losing the DB connection randomly.  I am using a non-XA driver.

The most likely suspect is the asynchronous database logging I added.
The sneaky thing is, I have used a thread pool:

```
ExecutorService ruleLoggingExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

and in the finally block of my process, I start off a new thread that calls down to the addLogs() method.

The code works for hours, days, and then during a totally unrelated query, it will lose the DB connection.  I have an inkling that the problem is that two concurrent inserts are being attempted.  But I don't know if putting 'synchronized' on the addLogs method would fix it, or if I need transactional code, or what.  Any advice?

---

In the DAO:

```
private EntityManager getEntityManager(InitialContext context) {
    try {
        if (emf == null) {
            emf = (EntityManagerFactory) context
                    .lookup("java:jboss/persistence/db");
        }

        return emf.createEntityManager();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(
                "Error finding EntityManagerFactory in JNDI: "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}



public void addLogs(InitialContext context, String key, String logs,
        String responseXml) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager(context);

    try {
        TblRuleLog log = new TblRuleLog();
        log.setAuthKey(key);
        log.setLogMessage(logs);
        log.setDateTime(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        log.setResponseXml(responseXml);

        em.persist(log);
        em.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception and hibernate.connection.release_mode value?

Comment: I haven't added that, so it's the default.  It's happened twice - The first time, I got the same error as this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867273/entitymanager-persist-method-hanging ... The second time, it was just "Connection reset"/"The connection is closed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the connection is closed after a timeout, perhaps due to transaction not being commited/rolled back (and locks not being released on the tables/rows).
Manual flushing looks suspicious. I'd use `entityManager.getTransaction().begin/commit()` and remove `em.flush()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  I am using Spring, with 
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" /> so I thought I didn't have to do transaction management myself.  Is that only for XA?

Comment: I get:  A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Comment: I changed to using UserTransaction, and I get "ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!"

Comment: I also see that in the startup, it says it is using CMT:  "org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory"

Comment: wow,that's quite a configuration.
Is there a particular reason for writing logs in a separate thread?
EJB spec forbids usage of thread-related API. If you're absolutely sure there's a need for asynchronous invocation use [EJB's @Asynchronous feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)

Comment: Yeah, the threaded logging is definitely not JTA friendly.  I made it asynchronous just because the database logging takes an extra 100ms sometimes, so the user is sitting there waiting, while i'm writing to the DB.  I will try the @Asynchronous thing...

Comment: @Asynchronous didn't seem to speed it up much.  I bet the JTA transactions are in place, so I don't need the begin/commit(), but the multi-threading was surely a problem.  So, I'm just going to do synchronous DB logging for now.